# Creating Web Application Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm trying to follow Google's [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating) on the Google App Engine. However, when I create a new Web Application Project I get the following error: "There was a problem generating the API metadata for your Cloud Endpoints classes: unknown protocol: c".
I have tried reinstalling Eclipse but whenever I create a new project I get the same error. As far as I can see, nothing is missing from the files Eclipse generates when I create a project, but I cannot compile because of the error.
Neither restarting Eclipse nor cleaning the project helps.
What have I missed?

I'm using Eclipse 4.3.2 and "Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3" 3.5.1.